# debsign: no entry data.tar.gz in archive error

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, gpg

I have created a binary deb package with `dpkg-deb` command. It is installable and works.

```
> dpkg-deb --build /test
dpkg-deb: building package `xxx' in `test.deb'.
```

Now I want to sign the package, but debsigs failed with errors:

```
> debsigs --sign=maint -k XXX /test.deb
no entry data.tar.gz in archive
```

Was it a problem with `dpkg-deb`?

**EDIT**

```
> ar t /test.deb
debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.xz
_gpgmaint
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of `dpkg-deb` produced a `.deb` package containing an `xz`-compressed `data.tar`, but your version of `debsigs` doesn’t support that, it only supports `gzip`-compressed `data.tar` components. To solve this, there are two possible approaches:

- upgrade `debsigs` to 0.1.18 or later (which is widely available, albeit not in Ubuntu Precise or Trusty, which is presumably what you’re using);
- force `dpkg-deb` to compress using `gzip`, by adding `-Zgzip` to the `dpkg-deb` command.